# How to properly set text caption on image with image on hover

Tags: angular, image, css, angular-masonry

i've been trying to use angular masonry. I've been trying to do something like when hovering over an image, the image will darken, and the caption will be more exposed (high-contrast) over the image to be able to read it properly. However, when i try to hover over the image, the caption, or in my case i call it header, within my image disappears (or apparently also affected by darkening the image).

To fully understand what i mean, please see this [Sample Code on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkymkj)

I've been trying to do this in purely css so that in my angular code would've handle only those data, and screen transition (routerlinks). I leave styling to CSS and other Libraries (i.e Angular Masonry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `.feed-header` is sitting behind the filter, so you need to set a `z-index` on that class:

```
.masonry-item
.feed-container
.feed-header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

Also, if you want to make the text contrast, you may want to set it to white on hover (to contrast with the dark filter). You can do so using:

```
.masonry-item
.feed-container:hover
.feed-header {
  color: white;
}
```

**[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtdwhq?file=src/app/app.component.css)**

Comment: ohhh i see, make sense, this does the job. next problem is how to auto contrast the text base on image color (if its dark, then text must be white. This is for the header when not hovered).

Comment: I don't think that will be possible with only CSS. You may be better off using something like white text with a black outline

Comment: something like text in a box kinda thing?

Comment: More like a text shadow. I've just updated the stackblitz, take a look at that

Comment: ohhh i see, it kinda float on screen, the text on top of the image. cool

Answer (score 0):

[This stackblitz should work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ertmy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

All I did was putting the header **before** the image and adding this as SASS to your CSS file :

```
ngxMasonryItem {
  .feed-text {
    color: white;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  &:hover {
    img {
      filter:  blur(2px) brightness(50%)
    }
  }
}
```

(An removing the previous filter you used)

in HTML, declaration order is important, and so is `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

[Try This Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvqlz5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

**CSS file**

```
.box {  

    cursor: pointer;  
    height: 468px;  
    float: left;  
    margin: 5px;  
    position: relative;  
    overflow: hidden;  
    width: 468px;  

}  

 .box img {  
    position: absolute;  
    left: 0;  
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
}  


.box .caption {  
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: .5em;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);  
    position: absolute;  
    color: #fff;  
    z-index: 100;  
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    left: 0;  
    opacity: 0;  
    width: 450px;  
    height: 450px;  
    text-align: left;  
    padding: 15px;
}  



 .box:hover .fade-caption {  
    opacity: 1;  
}
```

**HTML File**

```
<div id="mainwrapper"> 

<!-- Image Caption 3 -->  
     <!-- Image Caption 3 -->  
    <div class="box">  
        <img id="image-3" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"/>  
        <span class="caption fade-caption">  
        <h3>Fade Caption</h3>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>  
        </span>  
    </div>

   <div class="box">  
        <img id="image-3" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"/>  
        <span class="caption fade-caption">  
        <h3>Fade Caption</h3>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>  
        </span>  
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: If you need something like this hover caption you please let me  know so i can update your code

Comment: somewhat but i need the caption to be displayed always not on hover.. also, im trying to find ways to auto-contrast the caption based on the image color so it can be seen always but its another story